# Something happening with first line - tab function

Tags: java

```
    Piet van Gogh has an average grade of: 6-
    -^^--__-_-
    Vincent Appel
    Johannes Mondriaan
    Karel van Rijn has an average grade of: 7.0
    -^-----___
    No Name Matches Found
    Herman Vermeer has an average grade of: 4.5
    ------___-
    Johannes Brood
    Johannes Brood has an average grade of: 1.0
    -^-_-___-_
    Herman Vermeer
    There are no more student records available.
```

As you can see. Piet is slightly to the left. But I would like all the top lines to line up nicely with each other. I have played with the tab function, but then it just shifts all the first lines further to the right.

Anyone know how I can get Piet to move slightly to the right to line up nicely with the rest of the other top lines.

```
    void printStudentName(Scanner studentNameScanner) {

        String studentName = scannerToStringLine(studentNameScanner);

        out.printf("%s has an average grade of: ", studentName);


    }


    void identifyStudentName(Scanner studentNameScanner) {

        studentNameScanner.useDelimiter(" ");

        while(studentNameScanner.hasNext()) {

            printStudentName(studentNameScanner);

        }
void averageGradeOfStudent(Scanner inputScanner) {

        inputScanner.useDelimiter("_");

        identifyStudentName(stringToScanner(scannerToStringNext(inputScanner)));

        calculateAverageGrade(stringToScanner(scannerToStringNext(inputScanner)));

    }



    void calculateAverageGrade(Scanner inputScanner) {

        ArrayList<Integer> gradeArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); //Store grades in an array list.

        inputScanner.useDelimiter(" ");

        while(inputScanner.hasNext()) {

            gradeArrayList.add(inputScanner.nextInt());


        }

        mathScoreCount = gradeArrayList.size();

        determineFinalGrade(gradeArrayList, mathScoreCount);

    }



    void determineFinalGrade(ArrayList<Integer> gradeArrayList, int mathScoreCount) {

        cumulativeMathScore = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < gradeArrayList.size(); i++) { //Access each grade in the grade array list by looping through each element of the array list.

            cumulativeMathScore += gradeArrayList.get(i);

        }
        
        double mathScoreAverage = cumulativeMathScore / mathScoreCount;
        
        printGradeAverage(mathScoreAverage);

    }



    void printGradeAverage(double mathScoreAverage) {

        if(mathScoreAverage >= 5.5 && mathScoreAverage < 6) {
            
            out.printf("6-\n ");

        } else  {
            
            out.printf("%.1f\n ", Math.round(mathScoreAverage*2)*0.5);

        }

    }
```

Comment: showing your code might help us figure out the difference

Comment: Done. Code is added.

Comment: half of it is pointless. Just create one scanner on class level (instance variable) and re-use that. don't change single line pieces of code in methods of three or four lines. You need to check specifically at the lines where you print your data.

Comment: I dont follow what you mean sorry

Comment: you write way more code than you should, for one, that makes it harder to read. You should focus on the code that prints those lines, and check what the difference is between the first line, and the next lines

Comment: Where I print that first line, if I put a tab infront, then it just shifts all the first lines futher to the right. Its really only the first line that needs shifting to the right a little

Comment: Can you remove the unnecessary code from the post and only leave the part of the code, which has to do with printing ?

Comment: Also, do you know how to use a debugger ?

Comment: Upload your code to github and post the link here, also

Comment: I have uploaded the code above

Answer (score 0):

You should output a tab before printing the first line with the student name, it seems.

Then, everything will line up nicely.

```
out.printf("\t")
while(studentNameScanner.hasNext()) {
        printStudentName(studentNameScanner);

    }
```

Comment: I have tried that, but when I do that, it essentials moves everything far to the right, so I have a high gap going to the left.

Comment: That is what I get above if I utilise your suggestion.

Comment: See edited code. Just move insertion of the tab outside the main loop

Comment: Tried both ways, but it simply just gives me the layout as above. Maybe I cant change it?

Comment: Upload your code to github and post here with an explanation of how to run it